# Delete a document in Firestore and a file in Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). My document in Firestore has a field called `fileUrl` with the link of a file in Storage. I'm trying to delete the document first and then delete the file. (I don't know if I can do a batch for this)

```
this.competitionService.deleteCompetition(competition.id, competition.fileUrl)
          .then(res => {
            // Deleted
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

From main service

```
deleteCompetition(competitionId: string, fileUrl: string) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.competitionsCollection.doc(competitionId).delete()
        .then(res => {
          if (fileUrl) {
       this.uploadService.deleteFile(fileUrl).then(response => {
              resolve(res);
            }, err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
            resolve(res);
          } else {
            resolve(res);
          }
        }, err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Another service for the Storage

```
getMetadata(url: string) {
    const ref = this.storage.ref(`${config.storage_files}/${url}`);
    return ref.getMetadata().toPromise();
  }

async deleteFile(fileUrl: string) {
    const fileMetadata: FileMetadata = await this.getMetadata(fileUrl);

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.ref(fileMetadata.fullPath).delete().toPromise()
        .then(res => {
          resolve(res);
        }, err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

> FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_:
>   "Firebase Storage: Object
>   'files/https:/firebasesto…4c92-3a0e-45d4-adf3-5d81900f3953' does not
>   exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵
>   "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"↵  }↵}", name_:
>   "FirebaseError"}

I don't understand the cause of the error I am receiving.

My goal is, delete the document in Firestore and also, delete the file in Storage, then show a message to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build a reference to a file using its public https download URL like that.  You will need the path to the file in storage in order to build a reference.

I suggest also storing the path in the document to make it easier to delete later.  But you can also convert a download URL to a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) by using [`refFromUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#refFromURL).

Comment: I'm not using the public https download url. In my last snippet of the service, I'm using a method called `getMetadata` that returns me a valid `ref` but, for some reason the file is not being deleted. Maybe for some reason the `ref` is not being returned properly?

Comment: The error message looks like you have a https url in it.  Notice that it says "Firebase Storage: Object 'files/https:/firebasesto…4c92-3a0e-45d4-adf3-5d81900f3953".  There is https in there.  You're building that string with a variable called `url`.

Comment: Weird, I'm using the `getMetadata` method in another place and it's working fine. I can not find a `refFromUrl()` in Angular with `angularfire2`. Any idea?.

Comment: Don't know too much about angular.